# Sharepoint RichTextField not visible

Tags: asp.net, web

Hello I want to add a Rich Text Field to my Sharepoint Site. The Page shows with no problems but i cant see the Field.

```
<SharePoint:RichTextField runat="server" ID="RichTextField_Ergebnis" ControlMode="New" Visible="true">

</SharePoint:RichTextField>
```

Is there anything i missed?

Comment: Where are you placing the `RichTextField`, in web part or page layout etc?

Comment: a list form like new Element.aspx